# Creating a DataFrame in Pandas from a numpy array and a list

Tags: pandas

labels is

```
array([3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
      dtype=int32)
```

and species is

```
['Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Bream',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Roach',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Smelt',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike',
 'Pike']
```

I'm trying to understand how to create a DataFrame from these elements.

If I run the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([labels,species],columns=["labels","species"])
```

I get

> ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 85 columns

However, if I pass them in a dictionary as in

```
pd.DataFrame({"labels":labels,"species":species]
```

everything goes smoothly...

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reason for this error is that `pandas` expects each list within the list you're providing to be data for a single row. In your example, however, you are providing a list of lists, where each list contains all data for a single column, instead of all data for a single row. Changing the format from column-wise data to row-wise data using `zip` solves the error:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([*zip(labels.tolist(), species)], columns=["labels", "species"])
```

| labels | species |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Bream |
| 1 | Bream |
| 1 | Bream |
| 1 | Bream |
| 1 | Bream |

Comment: Many thanks Oxbowerce ;)

Answer (score 0):

A DataFrame treats a given set of data as a bunch of rows. As you passed two lists in the dataframe, it is taking them as two row passes here, so it's returning an error.

We can pass an array or list that contains row wise entries, as below:

```
data = np.hstack( # horizontal stack two columns, we can stack more one columns and pass to dataframe
    [
     labels.reshape(-1,1), # reshape for 1 column array
     species.reshape(-1,1) # reshape for 1 column array
    ]
).reshape(-1,2) # reshape because we need raw with 2 columns
```

[image]

Now we have this data, we can pass it directly to dataframes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=data,
    columns=["labels","species"]
)
```

[image]